# angular app works on http://localhost:4200, but I want https://localhost:44325

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application set up with an Angular front-end (using VS default setup) that was configured to run over an HTTPS connection.

I ran the project initially, and it worked fine on https://localhost:44325.
However, now, after editing my the .html and .ts files,the changes do not carry over. But when I run the server on http://localhost:4200, the changes carry over.

I want the changes to carry over on https://localhost:44325 since that is the port that my browser opens to when I run the application. How do I change this? Is it an npm issue? Is it in my angular app? Is it in Startup.cs?

**Startup.cs**

```
...
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Fallback", action = "Index" }
        );
    });
    ...
}
...
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing to the default configuration of an Angular/Core 2 app, I found the differences that made the difference.

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

**Environment.ts**

```
apiUrl: 'https://localhost:44325/api/
```

(in Environment.prod.ts, this is 'api/')

Answer (score 1):

You can run your angular app on desired port by editing .angular-cli.json file 
just add "server" section to "defaults" section in that file. You can replace 2500 with your desired port.

```
"defaults": {
    "serve": {
        "port": 2500
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error: `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)`

Comment: Is it possible your attempting to use a port which is already in use?

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager that the issue is that your browser cached the files you initially used on port 44325. You could try manually clearing the cache for that url in your browser. I added this to a web.config file for an ASP.NET project I worked on to help with a similar issue. Not sure if there's a similar mechanism for ASP.NET Core.

```
<system.webServer>
        ...
        <httpProtocol>
            <!-- TODO Remove for production -->
            <customHeaders>
                <!-- Disable Cache  -->
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
                <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache"/>
                <add name="Expires" value="0"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I've cleared my cache, tried it in incognito (before and after clearing cache), cleared my npm cache, and cleared VS's user cache just for good measure.
I've been banging my head on the wall for a while with this one...